# "Hopefully you’d make some time for me."

Tags: grammar, verbs

It's a never ending  barrage of doubts about a difference in meaning using auxiliary  verbs **would** as opposed **will**.

I've just written this sentence, and once gain was unsure whether I should have used would as opposed to will.

(BTW,is this sentence  correct: "*I've just written this sentence, and once gain was unsure whether I should  have used*" ?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `Hopefully you would make some time for me` and `Hopefully you will make some time for me` are grammatical, but they mean different things. The first is conditional on something else occurring before you making time for me even becomes an issue - "If I were to come to your city in February, hopefully you would make some time for me." The second assumes that you and I will definitely be in the same place at the same time, so the only question is whether you're too busy or not - "When I come for the interview tomorrow morning, hopefully you will make some time for me."

That said, I think what you might actually want to say is "Hopefully you *could* make some time for me", or even better, "Hopefully you *will be able to* make some time for me." This is because both the *will* and *would* constructions are asking about willingness, not ability - "Hopefully you will condescend to make some time for me" - which is not the sort of thing you'd routinely ask someone.

(For your other question, try "I just wrote the following sentence, and once **a**gain, I was unsure whether I should have used...".)

Comment: thanks, Martha (+1): then what is a good way to determine when to use would and when to use will?    also, why "*could*"?

Comment: I think you would say "Hopefully you can make some time for me," and turning "can" into "could" is a way of making it less direct, and more polite, without changing its meaning, really. Actually I think "Hopefully you would.." can work in that way vs. "Hopefully you will," but it seems less common?

Comment: I added some clarification about why "could" is preferable, although it's a bit hard to explain. As far as would vs. will, like I said: would is conditional, will is not. "Would you wear this [if I bought it for you]?" vs. "Will you wear this [tomorrow]?"